# Can play multiplayer one way but not the other

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've got Minecraft Pocket Edition 0.7.2. My multiplayer won't work. My friend and I have the full version, the same game version, and the same Android phone. I can play on my friend's world easily, but he can't play on my world. Why is that?

Comment: Multiplayer worlds show up at the bottom of your worlds list. Can you confirm that you're scrolling all the way to the bottom and still not finding the server?

Answer (score 1):

turn on "LOCAL SERVER MULTIPLAYER" in the option menu

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make sure that Local Server Multiplayer is turned on. If it is, then make sure that you are signed into your friend is signed into his/her Mojang account. If you are signed in you can join his/her, but if he/she is not he/she can not join yours.